# How to display/preview .doc and .txt files in the browser using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to preview my uploaded files with .doc and .txt in browser using react js.

Answer (score 1):

To view `.txt` files, it is very simple. Just import it and it should work.

For `.doc` you can use a library known as react-file-viewer.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer

Comment: it has a bug making the view where you use it pink